# water pump stops drawing water in few hours everyday

Tags: pump, well-pump

I have a water pump which draws water from a creek to irrigate the lawn. It had run for four months without problems. Starting last week, I notice that the pump would draw water for few hours only. Then, it would stop drawing, though still running, water. I turn off the pump, wait till the next morning, turn on the pump, and it would work for few hours before stopping drawing water again.

What could be the problem?

Comment: It sounds as if it might be losing it's prime. Is the water supply sufficient to maintain the flow demanded by the pump? Water level may have dropped or blockage occurred.

Comment: Also, a little more info would help. Is the pump filling a cistern? how is it irrigating the lawn? Sprinklers? Is it pumping up an elevation or is it relatively flat?

Comment: The water is fed to sprinklers through pipes. Elevation is less then 5 feet (calculated from the water lnlet in the creek to the sprinklers). Should I check inlet pipe for clogging, though there is no reason why it would be clogged.

Comment: SE unlike forums or other Q&A sites requires askers make a reasonable effort to solve the problem before asking, and show the work they did do. Please do that re: walking over there and inspecting the physical plant out at the creek.  It's a natural watercourse, change is in their ... Nature.

Comment: I replaced the pump with a new one, which works fine. So, the old one is damaged. Will send it to be repaired.

Answer (score 0):

You may have leaves or water creatures plugging the intake and the pump is overheating and shutting down. My farm used to have a 30 hp pump as I have water rights and every week or two I would have go pull the foot (a check valve in the water with a screen around it) and scrape off leaves and salamanders that got stuck. I now run a smaller pump with the same foot valve and screen and it doesn’t draw hard enough to plug up like it did with the big pump. So I would check for restrictions as that may be overheating the pump and a thermal safety may be protecting the motor.

Comment: There is nothing on the intake filter except mould. I cleaned the filter. It did not help.